# How to generate cert with -extfile option by bcprov.jar

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I need to write java code generate a X509 certificate by bcprov.jar.

My openssl.cnf is as below:

```
[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:TURE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA
basicConstraints = CA:true
```

I found the `JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder` with `addExtension` function will be ok, but I didn't know how the specify the desired section.

For example, I want to set `basicConstraints` in `[v3_req]` section to true, and  set that in `[v3_ca]` to false, how can I specify the section?

`addExtension` function only accept the `basicConstraints` parameter, and doesn't have a parameter accept the section.